# Formula to Count the duplicates as one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the the formula for the duplicate SKU on column A.

I have tried the formula on column B `=COUNTIF($A$2:A17,A17)` but it's not exactly what I want to do -  I want the result to be like on column C which put same value in each unique SKU and count in series

```
A         B         C           
sku001    1         1           
sku002    1         2           
sku003    1         3           
sku004    1         4           
sku004    2         4           
sku004    3         4           
sku007    1         5           
sku008    1         6           
sku009    1         7           
sku010    1         8           
sku010    2         8           
sku010    3         8           
sku010    4         8
```

Answer (score 2):

If `B2` is always `1` then:

In `B3` use:

```
=if(countif($A$2:A3,A3)=1, B2+1, B2)
```

Then Copy down to other B column cells:

[image]

Comment: You beat me on this one. :)

Answer (score 1):

So I put a check in for the first:

```
=IF(ROW()=2,1,IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2)>0,B1,B1+1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is another answer because the assumption that SKU are sorted was not assumed in the earlier definition of the problem. This assumes your SKUs are NOT sorted.

C2 `=1`

C3 `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A3,$A$2:A2,0)),MAX($C$2:C2)+1,VLOOKUP(A3,$A$2:C2,3,0))`

(Have taken your table as it is, you will have to shift it to column B, if your column B isn't needed)

Should look like this (illustrative pic):
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer i really appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

Assumption: if your SKUs are sorted, a simple `IF` formula would also do.
In cell `C2` you can enter the number `1`. In `C3`, you can enter

```
=IF(A3=A2,C2,C2+1)
```

It would look like this:
[image]
Pasted as Values to the right.

Comment: thank you guys for the quick response i have a question,what if the sku is not sorted then the formula will no longer work

Comment: @ramon My answer will work even if SKUs are unsorted.

Comment: @Chrismas007 - I'd debate that your answer works even when the data unsorted. As an example, if you rename sku008 as sku004, then the replaced sku004 takes up the value 5 of sku007, and doesn't roll back to sku004's original value of 4.

Comment: To the downvoter: any particular reason for a downvote? Wouldn't know why the downvote if there's no explanation.